# How to rotate 3D body around X axis in Altium Designer

Tags: altium, eda, 3d

I have a simple question about Altium Designer 13.1, to what I could not find the answer so far. How can I rotate a 3D body object around the **X axis**? I have checked at [here](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/PCB_Dlg-3DBody%28%283D+Body%29%29_AD) and on Google without any success.

I have a triangular based prism:

[image]

I want to rotate this with 90 degrees around X axis to get this:

[image]

This prism is the only object I want to rotate on the mechanical 1 layer, anyone knows the way to do this?

Also, how can I draw shapes in the Z-X or Z-Y plane like I do in the X-Y plane?

Comment: if you click on the 3D object's properties, there is an orientation value for each X Y and Z axis. Just adjust the X orientation value..

Comment: I have an **Extruded** 3D model type, which unfortunately does not have this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you place a 3D body, there is a button on the dialog box to convert to a STEP file. Step files allow independent control of rotation about any axis.

Answer (score 1):

Here is link to AD help about [Rotating a Standard 3DBody](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/PCB_Obj-3DBody((3D+Body))_AD#!3DBody-RotatingaStandard3DBody).

> The standard Extruded and Cylinder 3D Body shapes cannot be rotated around all three axes. For example, an Extruded object can only be rotated around the Z axis (looking down into the object), and a Cylindrical object can be rotated around the Y and Z axes.
>
> If an object needs to be rotated around another axis, it can be converted to a STEP object. To convert a free 3D Body object, select it in the workspace, then right-click and choose the Convert To STEP command from the context menu. The command will not be available if there is no object selected, or if there is more than one object selected. Once an object has been converted to STEP, it can no longer be re-sized in the workspace.
>
> [image]

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.